# Conditional expectation poisson distribution

Tags: conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

I am facing the following problem:

In an insurance company, one models claim occurrences of a given insurance portfolio by a Poisson process with intensity parameter \lambda$=52 (time is supposed to be measured in years).

1) What is the average time interval between two claim occurrences?
 I guess I have to take the expected value of the exponential distribution with parameter 1/52.

2) Assuming that no claim occurred during the first 5 weeks, what is the expected number of claims occurring in the next 47 weeks of the year? What becomes this expected number if one supposes that we observed 5 claims during the first 5 weeks?

How to solve this one? I don't know how to put it in equations :s

Answer (score 0):

1) Yep.

2) Memoryless property implies these are the same. The number of events in a window of length $t$ is Poisson($\lambda t$) distributed.